# here i tried to build up a program that encode the letters in a text by a shift amount and encountered this error whats the underlying problem?

Tags: python, typeerror

here is the code

```py
alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 
'x', 'y', 'z','a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 
'x', 'y', 'z' ]
text = input('enter youre text :\n').lower
shift_amount= int(input('enter the shift amount:\n'))
encoded_w  = ''
for letter in text :
    position = alphabets.index(letter)
    new_letter = position + shift_amount
    encoded_w += alphabets[new_letter]
print(encoded_w)
```

and here is the error:

```
line 7, in <module>
    for letter in text :
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
```

Comment: also how can i add code number line to my codes fast (in visual stuidio i cant copy the number line

Comment: *input('enter youre text :\n').lower()* Note the trailing parentheses. What happens if user input for shift amount is 100?

Comment: @Codist we can make an order to % the number (with the number of alphabets ) and than get the reminder that would be it

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies with the way you initialize `text`. `.lower` just returns a reference to this built-in function, it doesn't invoke it. Add parenthesis after it to call the function, so that `text` would indeed be the lower-cased input:

```py
text = input('enter youre text :\n').lower()
# Here -----------------------------------^
```

Comment: after doing so i got an other erorr stated : position = alphabets.index(letter)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: ' ' is not in list

Comment: hey @Mureinik would you like to we communicate farther you seem deep in concepts and engaged with the language iam learning Python but also want to leran it deeply do like to be my buddy ? really if there be a chance i can improve a lot

Comment: Does your input text contain a blank?

Comment: @alifraz, please mark this answer as the solution.

Comment: @gimix hi yeah the problem was that do you have any idea how i can add an attribute in my code to accept text with spaces?

Comment: Just don't shift spaces?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code. At least:

- the missing parenthesis in `text.lower`
- the fact that you don't handle spaces, punctuation marks, etc
- the possiblity of a user entering too large a value for the `shift_amount`

Here is a version which solves all of those. I just converted it to a function and made some minor adjustments, but the logic is unchanged:

```
def shift(text, shift_amount):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    encoded = ''
    for letter in text.lower():
        if letter in alphabet:
            new_letter = alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount) % 26]
        else:
            new_letter = letter
        encoded += new_letter
    return encoded

shift('the quick brown fox', 6)
'znk waoiq hxuct lud'
```

Just for fun, here is the same function as a one-liner (more concise and surely faster):

```
def shift2(text, shift_amount):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    return ''.join([alphabet[(alphabet.index(letter) + shift_amount) % 26] if letter in alphabet else letter for letter in text.lower()])

shift2('the quick brown fox', 6)
'znk waoiq hxuct lud'
```